# Qt5 RegExp не работает

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt, qregexp

```
QString str = "sdf com df ru";
qDebug() = str.indexOf("(com|ru)");
```

Выдаёт -1; Делал по Макс Шлее, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте несколько изменить код и все получится:

```
QString str = "sdf com df ru";
qDebug() << str.indexOf(QRegExp("(com|ru)"));
```

Вероятнее всего ваш код пытается строго искать подстроку "(com|ru)" в тексте и не воспринимает ее как регулярное выражение, ведь по факту в метод indexOf вы передаете строку, а не регулярное выражение.